# How to assign a custom function as parameter in Unity UI?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a scenario where multiple gameObjects are doing something very similar. onTrigger, a gameObject calls a function in a controller. (The destination function is different for each gameObject, but one gameObject always calls that one function)

This seems like a lot of duplicate code to me and I'd like to abstract the functionality; very similar to how the button OnClick() handles this case:

[image: Button OnClick()]

I naturally thought that was a good place to start and dug around the docs and forums and cobbled together something. Currently, my code is at:

```
using UnityEngine; 
using UnityEngine.Events;

/**
 * This script takes in a callback function, and a gameObject tag.
 * When OnEnterTrigger2D is executed, calls the call back function if the collision tag matches given tag
 *
 * Use it for reccuring events in multiple gameObjects like spawning obstacles when it hits spawn points,
 * or to call Endgame when player hits obstacles
 */

public class OnTriggerEnterCallFn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string targetTag;
    public EventTrigger.TriggerEvent callbackFn;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag(targetTag))
        {
            callbackFn.Invoke(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Thought that was all that was reasobable needed, but I seem to be missing something because, in the Unity UI, when I assign the class, my function is not visible at all:

[image]

My `FlappyBirdObstacleManager` has the function definition as `public void CreateNewObstacle()` and even making that `public void CreateNewObstacle(BaseEventData ed)` didn't have a positive effect.

What am I missing please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to not really require the `BaseEventData` parameter since you are passing in `null` anyway. I think you should rather simply use a parameterless [`UnityEvents`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) instead.

```
public UnityEvent callbackFn;
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked, thanks so much, I can't believe I've been searching around about 30 minutes now and didn't look into UnityEvent